# gcloud-node leaves behind files in /tmp?

Tags: gcloud-node

I have been using gcloud-node to upload files to GC Storage, but I noticed that I'm getting a multitude of these remnants in my /tmp directory:

> /tmp/3a1a48fa-3d83-4996-8e88-32bc01c36e86 
>   /tmp/3a1a48fa-3d83-4996-8e88-32bc01c36e86/.config
>   /tmp/3a1a48fa-3d83-4996-8e88-32bc01c36e86/.config/configstore
>   /tmp/3a1a48fa-3d83-4996-8e88-32bc01c36e86/.config/configstore/gcs-resumable-upload.json
>   ...

Is this normal? Is it just for large upload files?
Is there a way to configure which directory these files goes to (if they must be created?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is used when a resumable upload is started. You can opt-out of resumable uploads by setting `{ resumable: false }` as an option to either `bucket.upload` or `file.createWriteStream`.

The library used to write the file is [configstore](https://github.com/yeoman/configstore). `~/.config` is default, but you can override this by setting `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`.